# How to execute a program in set variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, where-clause

I'm writing the universal batch script for a Git upload.

I want to specify the location of the `Git` executable, if user doesn't provide one/is not located by `where` command.

```
C:\>@echo off

set Windows=C:\Windows\System32
set where=%Windows%\where.exe

: --- Git location ---
set "Git=..."    Executable

if %Git%==... (
    set "Git=%where% git.exe"    : <---
)

echo %Git%
where git.exe

%Git%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

The problem is, that executing a variable is different than `echo`ing it.

**How can I make `echo %Git%` output `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe`?**

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wanted to request from the end user the absolute path of the git executable, if it was not located in `%Path%`, then perhaps something like this may suit your purposes better:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("git.exe") Do Set "Git=%%~$Path:G"
If Defined Git GoTo Main
Set /P "Git=Enter the absolute path of your chosen git executable>" || GoTo :EOF
For %%G In ("%Git:"=%") Do If /I "%%~nxG" == "git.exe" If "%%~aG" Lss "d" If "%%~aG" GEq "-" GoTo Main
GoTo :EOF

:Main
Echo The absolute path to your primary git executable is %Git%.&Pause
```

The last line is for demonstation only, you would obviously change that to:

1. `"%Git%" [Args]`

or:

2. `Start "" "%Git%" [Args]`

---

As an alternative, if you really wanted to use `where.exe`, which would give you the additional benefit of checking the current directory, as well as `%Path%`, but could grab the location of more than one matching file, just replace line `3` of the script above with:

```bash
Set "Git=" & For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe "git.exe" 2^>NUL') Do If Not Defined Git Set "Git=%%~G"
```

Or:

```bash
Set "Git=" & For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "git.exe" 2^>NUL') Do If Not Defined Git Set "Git=%%~G"
```

In the case of multiple found files, this would define the variable with that which would be invoked by default should you have simply entered `git.exe` within that same environment.